# How to get the template filename which is currently been executed?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2003

I have a word 2003 .Dot template that stands in the `STARTUP` folder of the user.

I have in this template some modules with `autoexec` procedures.

In one of them, I want to read a ini file. If my template is `my.dot`, the ini file will be `my.dot.ini`.

In an `autoexec sub`, in a startup macro, reading `Application.ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` returns normal.dot... not `my.dot`.

How can I get the name of the currently executing template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the template which is currently executing through the ThisDocument.AttachedTemplate property.